# How I can update the value for a KeyValue array in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular/Typescript and I have this JSON response from an API

```
{
  "ID": 34397,
  "AssignedWorkers": {
    "Job1": 1,
    "Job2": 7,
    "Job3": 2,
    "Job4": 1,
    "Job5": 1,
    "Job6": 6,
    "Job7": 9,
    "JobN": 2
  }
}
```

The jobs are dinamic and can return any name. For this, I have defined the following interface:

```
export interface Deck {
    ID:             number;
    AssignedWorkers:     Jobs[];
}

export interface Jobs {
    [Job:string]: number;
}
```

I can obtain the value of every job, but I can not change the value of a particular job.

The function to update the object is this:

```
  updateJob(Job:string,Workers:number): void {
    for (var property in this.objOffice.Jobs) {
      if (property === Job) {
        this.objOffice.Jobs[property] = Workers;
      }
    }
  }
```

And the error is this:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Jobs'

How I can change the value of a Job if I only know the name of the job?

Comment: what is `this.objOffice.Jobs `?

Comment: Is the object with the response of the API with the structure of the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a slight mistake in your interface definition if you compare `Deck` to the API response.

Your API contains a Dictionary of Number, but in your interface you've defined Jobs as an array.

Assuming the API response is what you want to model I believe this is the correct interface:

```js
interface Deck {
    ID: number;
    AssignedWorkers: Jobs
}

interface Jobs {
    [Job:string]: number
}
```

Secondly I think it might be more beneficial to rewrite your function slightly so that it accepts a copy of the object it is going to mutate, as you otherwise won't be able to use the function except for that one hard-coded reference.

**With Copy, to avoid mutations**

```js
      updateJob(deck: Deck, entry: string, worker: number): Deck {
          // optionally create a copy to avoid unexpected mutations
          const updatedJobs = {...deck, AssignedWorkers: {...deck.AssignedWorkers}};
          if(entry in updatedJobs.AssignedWorkers) updatedJobs.AssignedWorkers[entry] = worker;
          return updatedJobs
      }
```

*usage*

```js
 this.currentJobs = this.updateJob(this.currentJob, "Job1", 10);
```

**Without copy, causes mutation**

```js
      updateJob(entry: string, worker: number) {
          if(entry in this.jobs.AssignedWorkers) 
            jobs.AssignedWorkers[entry] = worker;
      }
```

Comment: Very thanks, your answer are correct and works fine. I think that the principal problem in my code are the definition of the interface.
Very thanks

Comment: Please, one more question. How I can add a new item to AssignedWorkers?

Comment: Solved, with the same code add the new entry